# DIV:Overflow auto inside Table width: 100%

Tags: html, css, html-table, width, overflow

I am trying to have a `div` with a horizontal scrollbar inside a table that has 100% width:

```
<div id="div1" style="border: thin solid red; width: 800px; height: 150px;">
    <table id="table1" style="border: thin solid yellow; width: 100%; display: block;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="div2" style="border: thin solid black; width: 100%; height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
                    <div id="div3" style="border: thin solid blue; width: 1000px;">Hello</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I don't know why, but all browsers display `#div2` 1000px wide instead of 800px. Why is that?

How can I achieve displaying it only 800px wide and have a scrollbar inside `#div2`?

I don't want to specify the exact width for the `<td>` tag.

Answer (score 6):

Wrapping `div2` inside a single cell table with `style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%"` appears to be a solution. See http://jsfiddle.net/gvqVN/1/.

Comment: This is amazing.

Answer (score 1):

As I remember, the div-s and table-s don't like each other :) Try to give the 800px width to the div2. Also use `overflow:scroll` to have the scrollbars Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2XFka/)
And the code:

```
<div id="div1" style="border: thin solid red; width: 800px; height: 150px;">
    <table id="table1" style="border: thin solid yellow; width: 100%; display: block;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="div2" style="border: thin solid black; width: 800px; height: 150px; overflow: scroll;">
                    <div id="div3" style="border: thin solid blue; width: 1000px;">Hello</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that works, but I dont know the width of the div1 at the render time on server and also the width can differs because of some other content.

Comment: It is an example of complex situation. The outer div is sized by user (modal panel window) and I have no control on that (I use RichFaces rich:modalPanel).

Answer (score 0):

To div id `div1` add `overflow: hidden`

Your first line should looks like this:

```
<div id="div1" style="border: thin solid red; width: 800px; height: 150px; overflow: hidden;">
```

Comment: Well, it hides the overlapping part of the div3, but not add scrollbar to div2. :/

Answer (score 0):

Because `#div2`'s child element *(`#div3`)* has the width of `1000px`.

Comment: yes, the div3 is 1000px wide so I would like to show scrollbar on div2.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the 100% width on div2 with 800px, otherwise it'll just take the width of its child div3.

EDIT: If you can't use fixed width, you could set all table elements to display:block - standard tables have a very awkward way of handling dimensions, which is why your example didn't work.
Downside of this solution is, of course, that your table won't react like a table anymore...

http://jsfiddle.net/WKG5F/

Comment: Hmm, not good, because actually the div1 can be pretty far and difficul to find. And also there will be some flicker until the Javascript will set the appropriate value...